# Android: TimeStamp conversion question!

Tags: java, android, datetime

I'm parsing some xml for tv guide data and ran into this 18 digit timestamp (633934980000869533). Looks like C#'s DateTime ticks. Does anyone know how to convert this to regular java Date/Time?

Comment: Do you have good evidence that this *is* a .NET DateTime ticks value? What DateTime is it meant to represent?

Comment: (Just checked, and that would be November 11th 2009 in .NET. Does that sound right?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it *is* a .NET ticks value, you've just got to scale and rebase it.

Midnight on January 1st 1970 is represented by 621355968000000000 ticks in .NET, and 1 millisecond = 10,000 ticks... so:

```
public static Date fromDotNetTicks(long ticks)
{
    // Rebase to Jan 1st 1970, the Unix epoch
    ticks -= 621355968000000000L;
    long millis = ticks / 10000;
    return new Date(millis);
}
```

Obviously you'll probably want to extract those magic numbers into named constants :)

I've just checked, and the code above gives November 11th 2009, 1am UTC.

Comment: `ticks -= 116444484000000000l` instead of `ticks -= 621355968000000000` provides an accurate conversion.

Comment: @Quasar: Um, no. That's out by several hundred years. Where did you get that number from? I've made the literal an explicit long literal now though.

Comment: Actually, I was working on java 7 application talking to an AD server through Ldap. `621355968000000000` didn't seem to be working for me; it was off by 1600 years. So I had to do some trial and error around that and I ended up with `116444484000000000`. 

I just tried testing `621355968000000000` with the min & max tick values, and it gave the correct results. So, maybe it's the AD server sending miscalculated values.

Comment: @Quasar: Well where is the field documented for AD? I wouldn't *assume* it uses the same epoch as .NET. This code works fine for .NET `DateTime` ticks, as requested. What AD does would be a different question.

Comment: @Quasar: Actually, a tiny bit of hunting explains it: http://activelydirect.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/active-directory-epoch-vs-powershell.html "Active Directory stores time as the number of 100-nanosecond intervals (ticks) that have elapsed since midnight, January 1, 1601 UTC (GMT) in attributes such as LastLogon, LastLogonTimestamp, LastPwdSet and AccountExpires. PowerShell's epoch begins midnight, January 1, 0001 UTC." (Powershell ~= .NET in this case.)

Comment: Ah! That explains it. Thanks very much.