# Converting .NET time to Java time is two days off

Tags: java, c#, date, datetime, unix-timestamp

Yes, I know this question has been posed many times, but I am still unable to get a consistent result between .NET and Java.

There are a number of [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379548/android-timestamp-conversion-question) and google search [results](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_21589064.html) that refer to the constants:

```
long UNIX_EPOCH_IN_100NS_INTERVALS = 621355968000000000l;
long DOTNET_EPOCH_IN_MSEC_INTERVALS = -62135596800000l;
```

The first purports to be the number of 100ns intervals or 'tics' between UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00 (z yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) and UTC 1970-01-02 00:00:00, and the second is the difference between the .NET epoch and the Java epoch in milliseconds.

A post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949938/convert-date-between-java-and-net-2-days-off) reports a similar issue in the .NET world.

In the code below, I calculate the offset between the epochs and then compare to the published numbers:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("z yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date;
try {
  date = sdf.parse("UTC 1970-01-01 00:00:00");
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  throw new RuntimeException("Stupid java dates !");
}
System.out.println("Unix Epoch Date: " + sdf.format(date));
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
cal.setTime(date);
System.out.println("Unix Epoch Milliseconds: " + cal.getTimeInMillis());
try {
  date = sdf.parse("UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00");
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  throw new RuntimeException("Stupid java dates !");
}
System.out.println("Calculated DotNet Epoch Date: " + sdf.format(date));
cal.setTime(date);
System.out.println("Calculated DotNet Epoch Milliseconds: " + cal.getTimeInMillis());
date = new Date(-62135596800000l);
System.out.println("Published DotNet Epoch Date: " + sdf.format(date));
cal.setTime(date);
System.out.println("Published DotNet Epoch Milliseconds: " + cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

which generates the output:

```
Unix Epoch Date: UTC 1970-01-01 00:00:00
Unix Epoch Milliseconds: 0
DotNet Epoch Date: UTC 0001-01-01 00:00:00
DotNet Epoch Milliseconds: -62135769600000
Published DotNet Epoch Date: UTC 0001-01-03 00:00:00
Published DotNet Epoch Milliseconds: -62135596800000
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You have 5 digits in year, `00001`. Did you intend four?

Comment: But doesn't change the results ;-(